# Memory Leakage in Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have an application built in Spring Integration which has lots of Store procedure calls (Using int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway) and Prepared-statement calls (Using int-jdbc:outbound-gateway).

I am experiencing heap-size issue couple of times. Instead of increasing the heap size, I have taken heap dump and trying to analyze them using memory-analysis plugging in Eclipse. The report is showing me following two possible leakage,

> 382 instances of "oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement", loaded by
>   "org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader @ 0xb0bee3c8" occupy 225,949,088
>   (50.00%) bytes. These instances are referenced from one instance of
>   "java.lang.Object[]", loaded by "" Keywords
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement java.lang.Object[]
>
> ### org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader @ 0xb0bee3c8
>
> 295 instances of "oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement", loaded by
>   "org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader @ 0xb0bee3c8" occupy 49,342,360
>   (10.92%) bytes. These instances are referenced from one instance of
>   "java.lang.Object[]", loaded by "" Keywords
>   java.lang.Object[] oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement
>
> ### org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader @ 0xb0bee3c8

Can anyone please help me? What can cause these problems?
Configuration for int-jdbc:outbound-gateway is

```
<int-jdbc:outbound-gateway id="test1"
    data-source="dataSource" request-channel="testchannel1"
    reply-channel="testchannel2" query="select * from EMP"
    row-mapper="testMapper" max-rows-per-poll="0"
    requires-reply="false">
    <int-jdbc:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <bean class="com..service.NullReplyAdvice" />
    </int-jdbc:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-jdbc:outbound-gateway>
```

Configuration for int-jdbc:outbound-gateway

```
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition
            name="P_LIST" direction="OUT" type="#{T(oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes).ARRAY}"
            type-name="T_LIST" return-type="sqlReturnArray" />
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition
            name="RESPONSE_CODE" direction="OUT" type="VARCHAR" />
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition
            name="RESPONSE_DESC" direction="OUT" type="VARCHAR" />
        <int-jdbc:parameter name="USER_NUMIN" expression="payload.userId" />
        <int-jdbc:parameter name="STORE_NUMIN" expression="payload.storeId" />
        <int-jdbc:parameter name="ZONE_NUMIN" expression="payload.zoneId" />
        <int-jdbc:parameter name="SLOT_NUMIN" expression="payload.slotTodelete" />
        <int-jdbc:parameter name="RANGE_COUNTIN" value="0" />
        <int-jdbc:parameter name="APP_PARAMIN" value="DELETE" />
        <int-jdbc:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <bean class="com.test.HttpRequestInterceptor"></bean>
        </int-jdbc:request-handler-advice-chain>
    </int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>
```

Comment: When asking questions like this 1. Provide the version of Spring Integration you are using; 2. show your configuration.

Comment: The Version is 4.0.1.RELEASE.

Answer (score 1):

If the dao layer is implemented using spring jdbc/hibernate then this problem might not arise.
Make sure the prepared statements closed properly after completion of execution.